# Looking for issues with dynamically importing / executing / removing excel VBA module

Tags: excel, vba

Summary:
So I have a workbook that has been distributed and will need to be updated on occasion. After some research and investigation, I have opted for the workbook to import a networked .bas file (Visual Basic code module), execute the module's code to update said workbook and finally remove the module once completed.

Problem:
I was wondering if there might be any issues with this method, as it seems to work and be implemented too easily, when compared to an add-in for example.

My code is simple, in the workbook_open event I import and run the "update" module:

1)  VBproject.vbcomponents.Import MyModule

2) Execute MyModules code

3) VBproject.vbcomponents.remove MyModule

(2) and (3) are completed in another subroutine, otherwise the module's methods aren't recognised after importing and can't be used.

Thanks in advance for any issues that might come of this.

If the question is too vague or open ended let me know and I'll remove it or alternatively I can provide further specifics.

Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue I can think of is that for this to work, you need your users to accept to `Trust access to the VBA project object model`.

They might not want that,  reasonably, or be forbidden to do that, because it involves some security risks.

Imagine someone succeeds to drop a malicious `.bas` file with the same name/place of yours. You need to take measures against that, and convince the users and especially the security admins...

Comment: Yeah, understood. I had to enable that in the workbook. Just confirming, the setting is workbook specific and not application specific correct? Also, good point regarding malicious injection, I have to find a way to still share the module to excel but not have it editable or navigatable in explorer.

Comment: AFAIK the setting is Application specific not WB specific.